# Polymer Dart bind to a large model

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I need to display data from a fairly large Dart model. I simulate my model hierarchy like this:

```
// Tx contains a Ty
class Tx { Ty y = new Ty(); }

// Ty contains a Tz
class Ty { Tz z = new Tz(); }

// and Tz contains the field we want to display
class Tz extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String ws = 'foo';
  }
```

In a custom component I instantiate the simulated model and update it when the browser window is resized:

```
@CustomTag('x-a')
class Xa extends PolymerElement {

  Tx x = new Tx();    // instantiate my 'model'

  @observable String  w  = '-';
  @observable String  w2 = '-';

  //-----------------------------------
  Xa.created() : super.created();

  //-----------------------------------
  @override void attached() {
    super.attached();

    w = x.y.z.ws;    // attach the local variable to a variable in my model?

    window.onResize.listen((e) {              // browser window resize event
      x.y.z.ws = e.currentTarget.innerWidth.toString();  // works OK
      w2       = e.currentTarget.innerWidth.toString();  // works OK
      print('w=${w}  x.y.z.ws=${x.y.z.ws}  w2=${w2}');   // w never changes
      });
    }
  }
```

For completeness, here is the component instantiation:

```
<polymer-element name="x-a">
  <template>
    <div>w={{w}}. w2={{w2}}.</div>
  </template>
  <script type='application/dart' src='xa.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The `w2` String is correctly updated, as is the `ws` String deep down in the class hierarchy. But `@observable String w` never changes. I have tried a zillion combinations of `@observable`, `@published`, `@reflectable`, `@PublishedProperty`, and their friends. Does anyone know the spell to cast on the class variable to make it observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem with:

```dart
@CustomTag('x-a')
class Xa extends PolymerElement {

  Tx x = new Tx();    // instantiate my 'model'

  @observable String  w  = '-';
  @observable String  w2 = '-';

  //-----------------------------------
  Xa.created() : super.created();

  //-----------------------------------
  @override void attached() {
    super.attached();

    w = x.y.z.ws;    // attach the local variable to a variable in my model?

  void convert(List<ChangeRecord>changes) {
    w = changes.first.newValue;
  }

  x.y.z.changes.listen(convert);


    window.onResize.listen((e) {              // browser window resize event
      x.y.z.ws = e.currentTarget.innerWidth.toString();  // works OK
      w2       = e.currentTarget.innerWidth.toString();  // works OK
      print('w=${w}  x.y.z.ws=${x.y.z.ws}  w2=${w2}');   // w never changes
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: That worked well. Many thanks. And ..first.name will give the Symbol for the variable that has changed - I can select on this name to see which variable has changed. Will there be problems with exporting (i.e. dart2js) if I test for (name == #ws) ?

Answer (score 2):

```dart
w = x.y.z.ws;    // attach the local variable to a variable in my model?
```

is only a one time assignment.

I haven't used this myself yet but I think this should work

```dart
@ComputedProperty('x.y.z.ws')
String get w => x.y.z.ws;
```

Instead of

```dart
@observable String  w  = '-';
```

Comment: That worked and it's nice and succinct. It solves the exact problem that I proposed. I haven't ticked it as the accepted solution because it only works if x is in the same class as the declaration. In my case, it only works if the String w and the class instance x are both inside Xa. If the class instance x is an external "top level" object, there is no handle on x and it fails with noSuchMethod.

Comment: Just accept the answer you think solves your problem best. A workaround could be to add a getter like `String get xx => x;` to your `Xa` class and change `x.y.z.ws` to `xx.y.z.ws`. Another solution would be to use `x.y.z.ws` in markup instead of `w` but this would also require `x` to be inside `Xa` (by using the same workaround).